# Trying to save an xml file from an psql query?

Tags: xml, postgresql, psql

I run the following query of a remote postgresql db via psql in terminal:

```
\copy (SELECT cylinders.reduction, cylinders.name, print_suppliers.name FROM cylinders, jobs, print_suppliers WHERE cylinders.id = jobs.cylinder_id AND print_suppliers.id = cylinders.print_supplier_id AND jobs.id = 015983) TO '/Users/alex/result_sql.csv' WITH CSV HEADER
```

and get the correct csv file saved on my hd. However, I need an xml file saved locally and tried this:

```
\copy SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT cylinders.reduction, cylinders.name, print_suppliers.name FROM cylinders, jobs, print_suppliers WHERE cylinders.id = jobs.cylinder_id AND print_suppliers.id = cylinders.print_supplier_id AND jobs.id = 015983', true, true, '') TO '/Users/alex/result_sql.xml'
```

but I get this error:

> \copy: parse error at "query_to_xml". Without the copy...to, I am
>   getting perfect xml output.

Is there a way to save the xml output from terminal locally to my computer?

Thanks, Alex

Comment: try `\copy (SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT cylinders.reduction, cylinders.name, print_suppliers.name FROM cylinders, jobs, print_suppliers WHERE cylinders.id = jobs.cylinder_id AND print_suppliers.id = cylinders.print_supplier_id AND jobs.id = 015983', true, true, '')) TO '/Users/alex/result_sql.xml'`

Answer (score 1):

You need extra bracket after copy to copy from query, not a table. like here:

```
\copy (
SELECT query_to_xml(
 'SELECT cylinders.reduction, cylinders.name, print_suppliers.name 
  FROM cylinders, jobs, print_suppliers 
  WHERE cylinders.id = jobs.cylinder_id AND print_suppliers.id = cylinders.print_supplier_id AND jobs.id = 015983'
 , true, true, ''
  )
) 
TO '/Users/alex/result_sql.xml'
```

Comment: Hi Vao Tsun, Thanks a lot - this is exactly what I was looking for. Alex